# Want to find average nba 2k rating by college. Only one college appears

Tags: mysql, powerbi

So I have this written:

```
Select AVG(rating)
,college
FROM nbaplayers
WHERE College IN ("Texas", "Kentucky", "Duke", "Kansas","UCLA", "North Carolina")
ORDER BY college ASC;
```

But only the average for Texas shows up for some reason. Anyone know why?

Comment: Well, you didn't `GROUP BY College`

Comment: and it's not average for "Texas", it's average for all

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed group by
use following code

```
Select AVG(rating)
,college
FROM nbaplayers
WHERE College IN ("Texas", "Kentucky", "Duke", "Kansas","UCLA", "North   Carolina")
group by college
ORDER BY college ASC;
```